# Attempting to restate the question of whether the collatz conjecture has a nontrivial cycle as a combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, reference-request, collatz-conjecture

It occurs to me that the question about whether non-trivial cycles exist for the [collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) can be restated as these two questions (details on how this relates to the collatz conjecture can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4417018/48606)):

- Is there a general method for determining how many distinct values of $t_1, t_2, \dots, t_k$ exist for a given $k$ such that:

  - $t_k > t_{k-1} > \dots > t_2 > t_1 > 0$
  - $2\left(2^{t_k} - 3^k\right) < 3^{k-1} + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}3^{k-1-i}2^{t_i}$
  - $2^{t_k} - 3^k > 1$
- Would it follow that as $k$ increases, the number of distinct values approaches infinity?

It seems to me that the conjecture is false if any nontrivial cycle occurs. A non-trivial cycle occurs if $2^{t_k}−3^k$ divides $3^{k−1}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{−1}3^{h−1−i}2^{t_i}$ which would seem to me be a high probability if there are an infinite number of distinct values. Infinity does not mean this is necessary the case. More information is needed on the variability of the distinct values

Do my assumptions sound reasonable?  Are there any well known papers that investigate the collatz conjecture from this viewpoint?

---

**Update:** By "non-trivial" cycles, I mean cycles that involve $2^{t_k} - 3^k > 1$ and include all cycles listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Iterating_on_all_integers) as "trivial".

I have added a third bullet point above to clarify this point.  Thanks to Rosie F for noticing that it was missing.

Comment: I don't really see that distinct $t_k\to\infty$ as $k\to\infty$ would mean the conjecture false. Is it not the case that if half the integers are counterexamples, then $t_k$ would go to half of infinity, which is still infinity?

Comment: The conjecture is false if any nontrivial cycle occurs.  A non-trivial cycle occurs if $2^{t_k} - 3^k$ divides $3^{k-1} + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}3^{k-1-i}2^{t_i}$ which would seem to me be a high probability if there are an infinite number of distinct values.  You make a very good point.  Infinity does not mean this is necessary the case.  More information is needed on the variability of the distinct values.

Comment: Broadly speaking, I think the analysis performed by T Tao and others tries to determine bounds for the growth of $t_k$ as $k\to\infty$. For the reasons alluded to in my first comment, they acknowledge that such analysis is doomed to failure because the asymptotic vanishing of counterexamples is insufficient to disprove the existence of counterexamples, only that they vanish in relation to the integers. Yet many seem continue with the same methods, in the hope it sheds light on what's going on.

Comment: I am not clear how this applies to my question.  I am not saying that an infinite number of counterexamples disprove the argument (if one non-trivial infinite cycle exists, that disproves the collatz conjecture).  I am asking a question about division independent of the collatz conjecture or the work by Tao, as I understand it.  If there are an infinite number of distinct integers greater than $2x=2\left(2^{t_k} - 3^k\right)$, does it follow that $x$ divides at least one.  Of course, this does assume some level of variability in the infinite set which still needs to be shown.

Comment: I voted to close because your questions are too unfocused. You ask four questions in one post, with very little explanation as to what motivates the one questions you choose to ask.

Comment: It might help if you move your first comment into the question body as background/motivation.

Comment: With no restrictions, the number of possible distinct values is ${t_k}\choose{k}$ (which is equivalent to the number of ways you can write the parity vector of your sequence). But this is too broad. For instance, there are a lot of negative values for $(2^{t_k}-3^k)$ (e.g.$t_k=k$) but they couldn't lead to a cycle. Also, in a cycle, different sums of $t_k$ are divisible by $(2^{t_k}-3^k)$ (since each element of the cycle give an integer value for that division), which means that a lot of combinations are in fact very dependent one to another, messing with your probabilities.

Comment: Note that if you limit your search to $n_{min}$ and $t_k=\lceil k \cdot log_2 3\rceil$ (which is generally used in collatz sieve optimization), the number of distinct values that can lead to an integer division can be found in https://oeis.org/A100982

Comment: There are indeed non-trivial cycles (involving $-2$, $-5$ and $-17$ respectively) if the process is applied to all integers. Where do you restrict to the positive integers? It can't be $t_i>0$: you require the $t_i$ to be an ascending sequence, which shows that you do not use $t_i$ for the successive terms of a Collatz sequence.

Comment: @Rosie F I should add that point to clarify.  I consider the cycles that you are referring to as "trivial" since they are well-known and listed in the Wikipedia article on the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Iterating_on_all_integers).

Comment: Typo in first formula in Update : please replace $2^{t_k}$ for $2^{2_k}$

Comment: I'm writing up a small essay on this problem including the comparision with another method to estimate the number-of-orbits-to-be-tested. You can download it at https://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/CombinatoricalCountForNumberOfCyclicOrbits.pdf ; hints how to improve this draft are welcome. If you are more interested in this I might include something of it in my existing (or a new) answer...

Comment: Thanks @GottfriedHelms for sharing this.  I will read through it as I have time.  Looking forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add some more combinatorical information.

> Preamble: I'm used to use the following letters, which are different from yours, and I'm lazy to adapt this, please bare with me...
>
> I use
>
> - $N$ for the (N)umber of odd-steps (you have $k$)
> - $S$ for the (S)um-of-exponents-at-$2$ (or numbers of even steps in the  original Collatz-definition) (you have $t_k$)
> - $A,B,C,...$ or $A_k \mid _{k=1..N}$ for the single exponents,
> - with conditions $1 \le A_k \le A_\max$ and $S = \sum_{k=1}^{\small N} A_k$
> - where $A_\max = S- N+1$

I looked empirically for the number of possible sets of exponents $A_k$ with the restriction that $S=\lceil N \log_2(3) \rceil$ - that means the sets of orbit-candidates which must been tested for cyclicity.

Here, **rotations** of the exponents, for example $A,B,C,D$ and $B,C,D,A$, are taken as duplicate list entries of a cycle-candidate and are only inserted as one instance in the final list.

Here is the empirical list of sets of cycle-candidates for $N=2 .. 8$:

```
  N   S  minA  maxA      c         sets of exponents A_k for orbits to be tested
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ 2,  4,    1,   3]  ---  2        [1, 3][ 2, 2]
[ 3,  5,    1,   3]  ---  2        [1, 1, 3][ 1, 2, 2]

[ 4,  7,    1,   4]  ---  5        [1, 1, 1, 4][ 1, 1, 2, 3][ 1, 1, 3, 2][ 1, 2, 1, 3][1, 2, 2, 2]
[ 5,  8,    1,   4]  ---  7        [1, 1, 1, 1, 4][ 1, 1, 1, 2, 3][ 1, 1, 1, 3, 2][ 1, 1, 2, 1, 3][ 1, 1, 2, 2, 2][ 1, 1, 3, 1, 2][ 1, 2, 1, 2, 2]

[ 6, 10,    1,   5]  --- 22        ... ... ...

[ 7, 12,    1,   6]  --- 66
[ 8, 13,    1,   6]  --- 99

[ 9, 15,    1,   7]  --- 335
[10, 16,    1,   7]  --- 504
-----------------------------------------------------------
    for Collatz over the negative numbers, S=ceil(N*ld3)-1 (!!)
[ 1,  1,    1,   1]  --- 1   [1]                                            

[ 2,  3,    1,   2]  --- 1   [1, 2]                                         
[ 3,  4,    1,   2]  --- 1   [1, 1, 2]                                      

[ 4,  6,    1,   3]  --- 3   [1, 1, 1, 3; 1, 1, 2, 2; 1, 2, 1, 2]           
[ 5,  7,    1,   3]  --- 3   [1, 1, 1, 1, 3; 1, 1, 1, 2, 2; 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]  

[ 6,  9,    1,   4]  --- 10  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4; 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3;  ... ]    

[ 7, 11,    1,   5]  --- 30  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5; 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ... ]     
[ 8, 12,    1,   5]  --- 43  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5; 1, 1, 1, 1, ... ] 
...
==================================================================
          c = # orbits-to-be-tested (cyclic/repetitions removed)
```

My q&d-routine to detect this is extremely time-consuming; but the results and very likely the continuation of this can be found in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A241926), hidden in the following (infinite) rectangular array *(headers-lines are mine, "maxA" is reference to mine, square brackets indicate my empirical numbers $c$ of-orbits-to-be-tested)*:

```
table starts:
N:1  2  3   4    5   6    7    8    9   10   11    12       maxA
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 [1,]1,  1,  1,  1,  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,    1, ...    2
  1,[2,  2,] 3,  3,  4,   4,   5,   5,   6,   6,    7, ...    3
  1, 2,  4, [5,  7,]10,  12,  15,  19,  22,  26,   31, ...    4
  1, 3,  5, 10, 14,[22,] 30,  43,  55,  73,  91,  116, ...    5
  1, 3,  7, 14, 26, 42, [66,  99,]143, 201, 273,  364, ...    6
  1, 4, 10, 22, 42, 80, 132, 217,[335, 504,]728, 1038, ...    7
```

---

***Update***: The T()-formula in OEIS is extremely helpful!

Here is the list of systematic  $c(N)$ (= for each $N$) with $N=1..29$:
$$ [1, 2, 2, 5, 7, 22, 66, 99, 335, 504, 1768, 6310, 9690, 35530, 54484, 204347, 312455, 1193010, 4552275, 7056280, 27293640, 42181080, 165056400, 644637006, 1005633632, 3964522026, 6167026726, 24512635642, 38036848410,\ldots]$$
(Here the same for Collatz-over-the-negative-numbers, $S=\lceil N \log_2(3) \rceil -1$)
$$ [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 10, 30, 43, 143, 201, 728, 2652, 3876, 14550, 21318, 81719, 120175, 468754, 1820910, 2731365, 10752060, 16128424, 64188600, 254463276, 386782164, 1547128656, 2349343610, 9470798326, 14369476066,...]$$
$\phantom{aaaaaaaaaaaa}$ *(Note that there are $3$ cycles in the negative numbers)*
Your question

> - "Would it follow that as k increases, the number of distinct values approaches infinity?"

is surely to be answered as "yes"; the number of candidate-orbits (even if rotations are ignored) seem to be exponentially in $N$ (your $k$).

***Appendix:*** The Pari/GP-routines I've used is:

```
T(n, k) = sumdiv(gcd(n, k), d, eulerphi(d)*binomial((n+k)\d, n\d))/(n+k)  
 \\ this formula has been taken from OEIS-entry

l2=log(2);l3=log(3);ld3=l3/l2; \\ define common constants

{c_list=List([1]);   \\ initialize a List "c_list" with first value 1
for(N=2,29 , 
    S=ceil(N*ld3); \\ value for S required to allow cyclic orbit at all
    maxA=S-N; 
    c=T(maxA,N);
    listput(c_list,c); \\ append c at "c_list"
   );}
print(c_list)
```